# How do I read alternate GNOME configuration files

Tags: linux, configuration, gnome2

I have a number of versions of GNOME installed on a number of different hosts. All users have network mounted home directories. In some cases GNOME works poorly when reading configuration from the `.gnome2` directory. I would like to read config files from version specific directories. Is there any way to specify this when starting GNOME? Environment variables perhaps? I know how to move the `.gconf` directories but this is not sufficient. I need to read the `.gnome2` from a different path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [developer documentation](http://library.gnome.org/devel/libgnome/stable/libgnome-gnome-config.html) it doesn't look as if it was possible to use other directories than the default. You could have version-dependent directories and link them to ~/.gnome2 at login, however this breaks as soon as a user is logged in at two different hosts at a time.

Comment: Seems to be the only way and it is not a good way. Thanks anyway.